# LaTex Fonts: Greek formula symbols from mathpazo, rest in charter

Tags: fonts

I would like to use charter for text and formula symbols, excerpt for greek letters, these I'd like to do in palatino (**mathpazo**). I've tried around a lot with `\DeclareSymbolFont`, `\DeclareMathSymbol` and so on. But to be honest, I'm not close to a solution.

A minimal (not working) code example follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}

\DeclareSymbolFont{greeksymbols}{OML}{ppl}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\pii}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{25}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\chii}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{31}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mui}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{22}

\begin{document}
{\Huge $\pii \chii \mui $}
{\Huge $\pi \chi \mu $}
\end{document}
```

I've you could give any hints, this would help me a lot!

Thanks!

EK

Answer (score 3):

The family is named `zplm`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}

% just to do a comparison
\let\mdpi\pi \let\mdchi\chi \let\mdmu\mu
%%%

\DeclareSymbolFont{greekletters}{OML}{zplm}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\alpha}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"0B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\beta}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"0C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\gamma}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"0D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\delta}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"0E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\epsilon}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"0F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\zeta}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"10}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\eta}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"11}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\theta}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"12}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iota}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"13}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\kappa}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"14}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\lambda}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"15}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mu}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"16}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\nu}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"17}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\xi}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"18}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\pi}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"19}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rho}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"1A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sigma}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"1B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\tau}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"1C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upsilon}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"1D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\phi}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"1E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\chi}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"1F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\psi}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"20}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\omega}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"21}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varepsilon}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"22}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vartheta}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"23}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varpi}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"24}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varrho}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"25}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varsigma}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"26}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varphi}{\mathord}{greekletters}{"27}

\begin{document}

MathDesign: $\mdpi\mdchi\mdmu$

MathPazo: $\pi \chi \mu $

\end{document}
```

[image]